# prove a statement (complements of unions)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove this statement:

$$(A_1 \cup A_2)^c  =  {A_1}^c \cup {A_2}^c$$

where the $c$ means the complement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You can not prove it! Its not right. Either the Left Hand Side or the Right Hand Side needs to have 'intersection' in place of 'union' but not both simultaneously!This is true only in the case that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are empty sets!

Comment: @Manasi is right. Look up DeMorgan's Laws. Under complementation, unions become intersections and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was supposed to be an intersection at the right hand side. I corrected it

Comment: Don't correct it: you got two good answers. Others will have the same question as you and find the answers here. Leave this question as is, and ask a new question if you have one. Mho.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: This is true in the case when $A_1=A_2$.

Comment: Since you only have two sets a picture could be very useful and help you see where to go with this.

Answer (score 2):

You will have trouble proving that $(A_1\cup A_2)^c=A_1^c\cup A_2^c$, since it is not true, in general. (In fact, it holds precisely when $A_1=A_2$.) However, the following *are* true in general:

- $(A_1\cup A_2)^c=A_1^c\cap A_2^c$
- $(A_1\cap A_2)^c=A_1^c\cup A_2^c$

---

**Edit**: In response to your (temporary) correction, let me say that you are on the right track. Since $x\notin A_1,$ then by definition, $x\in\:???$ Since $x\notin A_2,$ then $x\in\:???$ Consequently, what can we say? For the other inclusion, you'll basically be doing the same thing, but in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of De Morgan's Laws. We want to prove that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$.

Let $x\in(A\cup B)^c$. Then $x\notin A\cup B$. So $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$. Therefore, $x\in A^c$ and $x\in B^c$. It follows that $x\in A^c \cap B^c$. Thus $(A\cup B)^c\subseteq A^c \cap B^c$. Now, let $x\in A^c \cap B^c$. Then $x\in A^c$ and $x\in B^c$. So $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$. Therefore $x\notin A\cup B$. It follows that $x\in (A \cup B)^c$. Thus $A^c \cap B^c \subseteq (A\cap B)^c$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false in the general case. For example, if $A_1$ is the set of integers ($\{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$) and $A_2$ is the set of positive real numbers, and the universe is the set of all real numbers, then  $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c$ doesn't contain $-1$ or $\frac12$, but $A_1^c \cup A_2^c$ contains them.

Comment: Do you want me to start a new thread with almost the same question? I just made a typo. I'm not sure people are gonna benefit from that typo? It will rather be a waste of space to start a new thread I think

Comment: I am still stuck on how to prove this statement, so help or hints is appreciated

Comment: Are you not planning to revert your 'fix' to your question? Let me know, please, so that I can delete this now-rendered-wrong answer. Re "I am still stuck on how to prove this statement, so help or hints is appreciated", see the other answer. See also [how to get answers to your questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers); one suggestion that should perhaps be on that page is "don't drastically change the question after it has good answers".

Comment: I see what you mean. I will revert it, so the answers provided match the old question that had a crucial typo, and create a new one with the right question