# Proof of statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove this statement:

$$(A_1 \cup A_2)^c  =  {A_1}^c \cap {A_2}^c$$

What I have realized so far, is that

$$(A_1 \cup A_2)^c \implies x \not\in A_1 \textrm{ and } x \not\in A_2 \implies x \not\in (A_1^c \cap A_2^c)$$ (Though I'm not sure if my approach is correct since I'm stuck)

but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way to do this is by means of a truth table.

Comment: A matter of taste is to consider the case where one of the sets is empty.

Comment: @Cameron That post asks to prove $(A\cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$, which is false, and the answers indicate as much.

Comment: @amWhy: Originally, the OP corrected it to say what was actually intended. I did not realize that it had been uncorrected.

Comment: @CameronBuie [The source of the confusion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551994/prove-a-statement-complements-of-unions#comment1174375_551994).

Answer (score 1):

$x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)^c$ **iff** $x \notin A_1 \cup A_2$ **iff** $x \notin A_1 $ and $x \notin A_2$ **iff** $x \in A_1^c $ and $x \in A_2^c$ **iff** $x \in {A_1}^c \cap {A_2}^c$.

Hence $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c = {A_1}^c \cap {A_2}^c$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I was wondering myself...

Answer (score 1):

First write down the definition of the first set, that is:

for $\forall x \in (A_1 \cup A_2)^c$, $x$ is not in $A_1$ and/or $A_2$

$x$ is not in $A_1$ and $x$ is not in $A_2$

hence $x \in A_1^c \cap A_2^c$

hence $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c \subset A_1^c \cap A_2^c$

You can prove it also the other way around to get the equality , try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This much of what you posted is correct:

$$(A_1 \cup A_2)^c \implies x \not\in A_1 \textrm{ and } x \not\in A_2$$

Continuing on, using first the definition of the complement of a set, and then the definition of set intersection: $$\begin{align} \underbrace{x \not\in A_1}_{\large\iff x\in A_1^c} \textrm{ and } \underbrace{x \not\in A_2}_{\large \iff x \in A_2^c} & \iff x \in A_1^c \underbrace{\text{ and }}_{\cap} x\in A_2^c \\ \\ &\iff x \in A_1^c \cap A_2^c\end{align}$$